# How can I cut out the below pattern from a string using Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2010

I have a string which will have the word "TAG" followed by an integer,underscore and another word.

Eg:  "TAG123_Sample"

I need to cut the "TAGXXX_" pattern and get only the word Sample. Meaning I will have to cut the word "TAG" and the integer followed by and the underscore.

I wrote the following code but it doesn't work. What have I done wrong? How can I do this? Please advice.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String sentence = "TAG123_Sample";
        String pattern=@"TAG[^\d]_";
        String replacement = "";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        String res = r.Replace(sentence,replacement);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: try this:  `@"TAG\d+_"`

beacuse `[^\d]` probably just says "no digit will follow TAG" so just use \d+ which says "more than one digit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently negating (matching **NOT** a digit), you need to modify the regex as follows:

```
String s = "TAG123_Sample";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"TAG\d+_", "");
Console.WriteLine(r); //=> "Sample"
```

**Explanation**:

```
TAG      match 'TAG'
 \d+     digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
 _       '_'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Split` for this:

```
string[] s = "TAG123_Sample".Split('_');
Console.WriteLine(s[1]);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this will work in this case for sure:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(sentence , 
    @"^   # Match start of string
    [^_]* # Match 0 or more characters except underscore
    _     # Match the underscore", "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Answer (score 1):

No regex is necessary if your string contains 1 underscore and you need to get a substring after it.

Here is a `Substring`+`IndexOf`-based approach:

```
var res = sentence.Substring(sentence.IndexOf('_') + 1); // => Sample
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/SJ3Gss)